# Search for WORD at line-start and include all lines before that are not blank

Tags: python, python-re

Let's look at this text:

```
foo bar
foo bar

bar foo

bla
blu
WORD foo bar

foo bar
```

I'd like to have a python `re.search` expressions that will match the line starts with `WORD` and all the non-blank lines before.

So from the text above, it should extract

```
bla
blu
WORD foo bar
```

My non-working approach is:

```
re.search(r'\n\n.*(?!\n\n)WORD.*?\n', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Why do you have to use *re* for this?

Comment: @AlbertWinestein Because my actual search phrase is a bit more complicated. I tried to abstract it to the core problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

```
re.search(r'\n(.(?!\n\n))*\nWORD.*?\n', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Searches for a line starting with `WORD` and includes that line with all other non-blank lines.

Comment: it also matches the first two white lines

Answer (score 1):

To extract the exact same subtext use this regex

```
\b((?!\n\n).)*WORD.*?(?=\n)
```

See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Id76tg/1)

##### Python Example

```py
import re

match = re.search(r"\b((?!\n\n).)*WORD.*?(?=\n)", text, re.S)
if match:
    print(match.group())
```

##### Output

```
bla
blu
WORD foo bar
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified by using a list. Then the pattern matching only has to be done for a single line - i.e., not taking into account what's been seen before. Something like this:-

```
FILENAME = 'foo.txt'

stack = []

with open(FILENAME) as data:
    for line in map(str.strip, data):
        if line:
            stack.append(line)
            if line.startswith('WORD'): # simplification
                print(*stack, sep='\n')
                stack = []
        else:
            stack = []
```

**Output:**

```
bla
blu
WORD foo bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any extra flags

```
text = # 

regex=r'(.+\n)+WORD'

m = re.search(regex, text) # match object

m.group()
#bla
#blu
#WORD
```